# xkeyval define@choicekey - which macros are defined without <bin>?

Tags: macros, package-options, xkeyval

The [xkeyval manual](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xkeyval/xkeyval.pdf) gives the following syntax for `\define@choicekey*`:

> `\define@choicekey*[〈pre〉]{〈fam〉}{〈key〉}[〈bin〉]{〈al〉}[〈dft〉]{〈func〉}`
>
> ... the optional `〈bin〉` should contain either one or two control sequences (macros).
> The first one will be used to store the user input used in the input check (hence, in
> lowercase when the starred version was used)

What macros get defined if I *don't* use `<bin>`? And are they defined throughout my document, or just for the scope of `<func>`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the example on page 7 of the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{fam}{key}{%
  I will first check your input, please wait.\\
  \XKV@cc*+[\val]{#1}{true,false}{%
    The input \val\ was correct, we proceed.\\
  }{%
    The input \val\ was incorrect and was ignored.\\
  }%
  I finished the input check.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setkeys{fam}{key=true}

\val

\begingroup
\setkeys{fam}{key=blurb}

\val
\endgroup

\val

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

so you see that `\val` keeps the value it was given when the key was set, respecting grouping.

I discovered this when a user on the GuIT forum was defining a `\val` macro and got some surprises. The document used the `suftesi` class, which exploits `xkeyval` and had something like

```
\define@choicekey{}{structure}[\val\nr]
    {book,article,collection}[book]{%
      [...irrelevant code...]%
    }
```

and other similar settings. Each setting of a key using `\val` resulted in clobbering the definition of `\val`.

I wrote to the package author, asking him to change the examples so the “bins” had some special name with `@` in them, but got no answer.

At least, `suftesi` changed the code to use `\suftesi@val` and `\suftesi@nr` as bins.

If you don't use a bin, no macro is defined at the user level, only internal ones.

---

I just checked in the LaTeX tree and my suspect revealed true: *many* packages use

```
\define@choicekey+[<pre>]{<fam>}{<key>}[\val\nr]{...[code]...}
```

because the manual of `xkeyval` doesn't clarify that a definition of the bins remains after the key has been set.

This will not have adverse effects if the key is only set at package loading and a user adds a personal definition for `\val` or `\nr`. But if the key is set at begin document (or later), quite likely this will clobber the user's definition.

Too bad. Anyway, nowadays there are much better key-value based interfaces than `xkeyval`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the choice is not up to me, since I'm trying to submit a PR for polyglossia, which uises xkeyval.  Anyway, reading through your answer - I only see examples with the <bin> macros being defined. Again, what's the default when you don't set it?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not sure there *is* a default to begin with.

Comment: @einpoklum For the value one can possibly use `\XKV@tempa`, but I wouldn't try. No default for the second token, as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm pretty sure macros are defined when you don't specify <bin>. I guess I'll just have to look at the source.

Comment: @einpoklum As far as I can see from `\tracingassigns=1` only `\XKV@tempa` receives the value.